# can XInclude be used on stream input?

Tags: xinclude

I would like a portable solution to creating a multiply nested XML document using XInclude. I am using `<xi:include href="foo.xml">` elements and taking the input from a stream. So far this fails (I am using XOM which has its own XIncluder) which reports it cannot find the base URL for the `href`. I am wondering if this is a general problem (see [XercesDOMParser and XIncludes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155844/xercesdomparser-and-xincludes) ). If so are there general workarounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A relative URI like `foo.xml` is useless without the context of a base URI with which to work out that e.g. if the base URI is `http://example.net/bar/baz.xml` then the absolute URI of the resource is `http://example.net/bar/foo.xml`.

This base URI can come from:

1. The URI that the XML in question came from (clearly not applicable to a stream alone).
2. A URI passed to a parser by mechanisms specific to it.
3. `xml:base`
4. Means specific to a given XML application (not advisable, but sometimes necessary for compatibility with other formats, e.g. the `<base />` element in XHTML duplicates `xml:base` unnecessarily and with less flexibility, but is required for compatibility with HTML4.01 and earlier).